# Video List Player?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a few movies for my daughters website for kids that I would like to have play in a .png image of a old tv.

Question is,
How can I make a list of videos on a move.html that will play on separate page "movetitle.html with out having to make each individual page (movietitle1.html,movietitle2.html,movietitle3.html, and etc.)? 
Cause I have embed each movie in each html document then played using iframe!

Comment: Can please make you question more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No iframe necessary.  Just make the tv.png the background image of the video container div, and then just position the video inside of it.  You can use JavaScript to make a playlist just by adding event listeners to the video listening for one video to end, to queue the next one to start.  If you need more details/have more specific questions, feel free to ask.  This is actually my specialty :-)  [-Dan Goodspeed](http://dangoodspeed.com/)

Comment: Iframes are not the way to go.  Just putting the movie right in the HTML is best.  Are the movies HTML5 compatible (MP4 or the like)?  Are they all the same size (widthxheight)?  Will the list be a drop down menu, or just a series of links?  Will it be a public online website, or something that will just run on the local computer?

Comment: mp4 different sizes! html5 compatible!  Going to have series of links on public website.

Comment: Are they videos/.png publicly hosted yet?  I was thinking about making a mock-up on jsfiddle to get you started, and it would be easier to use the actual files.

Comment: Ok, this should work for you - http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/AyRNQ/7/  I made the controls on the TV a clickable space to return to the movie listing.  To add a movie, it's as simple as adding in one line of code for a new movieList object.

Comment: forgot to include the jquery so its working but when u hit the space u made to go back it doesn't work! But I do like the concept gonna work it into my new setup! Once bugs are fixed!  Thanks

Comment: I just tried the page you made and clicking the VHF/UHF area on the TV does go back for me.  Did you figure it out?  I also looked at your source code and saw you're including Flowplayer... you shouldn't need FLowplayer for anything in my set up.  Maybe I guess as a fallback for browsers that don't support the video files... but I don't think this page would need broad browser support.

Comment: ya it goes back to the list but when u click another video it doesn't play it!!!  Also i delete the flow player!

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think to check that.  It's because the bindings are removed when the links are removed.  Probably the best way is just to hide the links when the video is playing, then reshow them when wanting to see the links.  Or the easiest way is to just move the bindings into the buildPlaylist function, like this - http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/AyRNQ/28/ PS- feel free to upvote/accept any of my posts/comments that are helpful.  It's not very often that a question is asked that is so suited toward what I do :-)

Comment: perfect! thanks for the schooling! any suggestions where I can read up on coding like this new to this type!

Comment: I'm not sure if the type of coding has a name, it's just how I code.  Is there anything specific you're wondering about?  Are you new to jQuery?  And I'm not 100% sure I know what you mean by dummy the links... can you be more specific?  You just don't want the jsfiddle links that point to the TV image from your site here?

Comment: OK ran into one problem the list once it reaches 11 anything over passes thru the tv and not making scrollable??  Also is it possible to make the video center horz. on tv based on video size?

Comment: Also does this code already preload video?

Comment: It doesn't preload any video before you click on them, as they will be far to big to download all at once.  To get the scroll bar to show, add "overflow-y:auto;" to #videoPlayer.  And lastly, I assume you mean center vertically, not horizontally.  It is possible dynamically by binding a listener to the video each time it's loaded to get the height from the metadata, and set the margin-top accordingly.  Or, you could just use an array similar to the movieList URLs, and hard code in the margins for each of them.

Comment: not sure about putting code for the vertical!

Comment: As for the website it worked but now the videos have scroll bars!